# How to develop a good game project?

Tags: opengl, c++, java, jni

I have enough experience in both `C++` and `Java`, since I've been working on them a lot. My graduation project is, in my case, a game (I still have almost 8 months remaining). I already took down the basic ideas behind it, but I'm still unsettled on how to implement the whole project. The best method, in my opinion, was to perform low level operations such as window handling and *OpenGL* rendering using libraries implemented by me in C++ and more game-oriented features with Java.

So, basically I'm headed to create the game engine with C++ and any game related code with Java, through the use of the *Java Native Interface* to perform engine calls from the *JVM*. Can this be considered a good idea or it is that bad?

Comment: Very interesting question but why not use an already made and currently still developed library in java, such as libgdx ? Is it not allowed ? Or you just want to do this for the experience ?

Comment: Questions like this that ask "is this a good idea?" (or related, questions about how to start a project and which technology to use) are generally discussion-oriented and are considered off-topic here. There's nothing that seems immediately *terrible* about your plan, but if you want to ask about it you may be better off in the [chat] or on a forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: All I wanted was just an answer about the correctness of the technology I described, anyway thanks for support

Comment: @Shiro I want to do in that way for experience

Comment: If it's your first game project, and you're on a schedule, I would put aside "R&D" (_"for experience"_) and stick to a single project, _"making a game"_. You'll encounter enough issues only with the development of your game, I would not add the BIG overhead of designing/programming a cross-language architecture and designing and writing a rendering engine. KISS, keep it simple and small. At least at first, until you know more where you're going. And if it is your first game project, "performance" is not a good reason, IMHO, to mix c++ and java.

Comment: It's not my first time I've been making games, I already made other game engines by myself, completed one or two projects and I have even been working with modern OpenGL. Performance is not my issue, and I just thought to do it that way to add some more things to the project, since it's really a simple game to make.

Comment: Oh, well in this case, as it's been said, it's pretty hard to tell. Depends on the goal you aim. Do you want to compare the same game with the same architecture, but one using a c++ base engine and the other with a Java base engine, and compare if one outperforms the other? Or just see if you're able to do it? Really, it's too opinion based, or too broad unfortunately.

Comment: The main purpose of the question was to understand if making everything with Java (so using LWJGL) was better or worse than dividing the architecture by implementing the engine in C++ (so using a different library) and implementing the game logic with Java

Comment: I explained what I really needed to ask in the wrong way, I'm sorry